# Get external public IP from command line in Fortinet

Tags: fortinet, fortigate

Is there any way to know the public IP address of a Fortinet? There are many services such as icanhazip.com that tell you the current IP.
In Linux, I would just run:

```
curl http://icanhazip.com
```

How could that be done with Fortinet (I am using a fortigat 200B in case it's noteworthy)

Some cases come to my mind:

- I want to know the default GW I am using in a fast way
- My DSL router is NATing, so I don't know directly the public IP  address
- Or IPs assigned as DCHP/PPPoE (as stated by @mbrownnyc)

Since it doesn't seem possible to use any form of curl/wget from the command line, another option would be to use nslookup (still not sure if it's a valid FortiGate command or only for some forti* products).
See here for what I mean [getting external IP](http://osxdaily.com/2013/07/16/quick-external-ip-address-command-line/)

Comment: Do you want to grab the IP address of an interface that has an IP assigned via PPPoE or DHCP?

Comment: Added some more information

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick how to do it. It requires access to an SSH server available from the internet, preferably a linux machine.
Simply log in to the server via SSH from the FortiOS CLI:

`execute ssh user@sshserverip`.

After logging in, drop off by typing `exit` and then log in again. You should then see a line saying:

`Last login: date & time from: X.X.X.X`.

X.X.X.X is your public address, when you logged in first time as described above.

> The line "Last login:" is displayed by default unless it is deleted from SSH daemon config.
>
> In case the server displays a DNS entry instead of the IP address, simply resolve it by typing `nslookup dnsentry`

Comment: not all DSL/cable/etc. ISPs have proper forward IPs for their reverse IPs on these dynamic IP systems;(

Comment: You can `execute ssh ident.me` and save a roundtrip. https://api.ident.me for docs.

Answer (score 2):

Try "diagnose system waninfo ipify", it will show you the public facing IP address, GeoIP information and if you're on FortiGuard's blacklist.
It also takes a source IP address as optional argument, if you have multiple internet lines. (tested on FortiOS 6.2)

Answer (score 1):

I got here because I was wondering the same thing.
Sure, you can just plug a PC into the internal port with a crossover cable,
but I thought there had to be another way to get it.

So the solution was to have a computer on the external side of the fortigate with wireshark installed.
Then in the fortigate command line, you

```
execute ping "computer IP address"
```

while the computer is running wireshark with the "icmp" display filter.

Now you should get the ping requests from the fortigate with its external IP adress.

Comment: Nice solution, I still need an external ssh box but currently it's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the `default gateway` I am using in a fast way

Performing a `traceroute` to a known address out of the interface you wish to target, in my example Google DNS.

from the FortiOS CLI:

```
execute traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

> My `DSL` router is `NATing`, so I don't know directly the public ip address

This is tricky, if not impossible from the FortiOS.  Open to other responses as I could be missing something.

An alternate to just hitting a web site to get the IP you are accessing that site with, is to find a STUN/ICE client and find a public STUN/ICE server that will return the info you wish.  But you can't do either of these things from the FortiOS.

> Or `IPs` assigned as `DCHP`/`PPPoE` (as stated by @mbrownnyc)

The IP assigned to a Fortigate can be reviewed as follows:

```
show system interface
```

You can see this in [the dope little video collection on the Fortinet site](http://www.fortinet.com/videos/fortigate_checking_internal_interface_ip_address.html).

Comment: The traceroute might be a good option to find the defatult gw, at least you will know the wan interface, see on the original post another idea I had..

Comment: take a look at `execute` in the docs to learn how to use `nslookup`.  I had no idea about `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`.  That's great!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external IP from your provider - I have one way to know it via CLI:
important - after this line don't press enter, press `?`

```
$ show system interface ?
```

So after this command you'll see the external address under wanX pppoe

Comment: Doesn't do all the features I need, it shows the interfaces ips, but doesn't hint the default gw, and doesn't work when behind a NAT device.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use FortiDDNS on the appliance in Network/DNS (use Fortinet DNS to use FortiDDNS)

enter a FQDN and apply. return to same place and you will see your WAN IP

Comment: In what version are you seeing this feature?, I'm on 5.6 and there's nothing like that in Network -> DNS

Answer (score 0):

By just doing:

```
diagnose ip address list
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you're behind a NAT

Answer (score 0):

Or just get it from the Status page on the dashboard of the Fortigate if you can access it via the FortiCloud remote access console